# Is pyvisa for python3.x necessary to communicate in SCPI with lab instruments?

Tags: python, visa

Can I just simply make TCP socket connection and send formatted strings? In general cases what should the formatted string be?

****Safe to assume: ********

- TCP connection has been successfully made to instrument
- socket.sendall('*IDN?')... works

However, I'm stilling getting -113 header errors.  I would like to know what is the correct syntax:

1. ':AA\n'
2. 'AA [value] \n'
3. 'AA [value]\n'
   4)':AA'\n
   etc...

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context and add some code regarding what you expect vs what you are getting?

Comment: 1. You can make simple TCP socket connection if your instrument supports this possibility. Sometimes this is called SCPI-RAW or "raw TCP" mode. 2. Where do you see this "-113" errors? 3. Check what type of EOL character(s) you instrument expects in this mode.

Comment: A header error means that your instrument doesn't recognise the the command your are sending. Check the manual or let us know the instrument.